# he had it checked by the manager

Tags: perfect-constructions, causatives

*He had it [checked by the manager].         [passive]*

In the Cambridge Grammar of the English Language is on page 1174 written in connection with this sentence this: "The past participle form of the verb has two uses, perfect and passive. Clauses with a perfect past participle as head occur as complement to auxiliary *have*, and accept progressive and passive *be*, while those with a passive past as head accept no auxiliaries".

Is the above sentence really example of a passive past perfect? I consider it more likely as the causative, i.e. the structure "have sth done".

Comment: shouldn't  the passive past perfect  be *it had been checked by the manager*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not a perfect construction: the *had* here is not an auxiliary but the lexical verb in the sentence, with a causative sense:

> He caused it to be checked by the manager.

It is the infinitive *to be checked* which is passive; the infinitival clause can be cast into the active voice without involving *had*.

> He had the manager check it = He caused the manager to check it